# Call prolog predicate from python

Tags: python, prolog, ffi, swi-prolog

I have some `.pl` file and I want to call predicate declared in it from python script. How can I do that?

For example, `test.pl`

```
rD( [], Ans, Ans ).
rD( [X|Xs], Ans, Acc ) :-
    member( X, Acc ),
    rD( Xs, Ans, Acc ), !.
rD( [X|Xs], Ans, Acc ) :-
    \+member( X, Acc ),
    append( Acc, [X], AccNew ),
    rD( Xs, Ans, AccNew ), !.
```

Working like

```
?- rD( [1,2,3,4,5,4], X ).
X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].
```

I want to call `rD` somehow from python script and get answer in result variable

```
result
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

ps: it is just an example, and I don't want to rewrite my current Prolog program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not that I have a direct experience with it, but there is a project called [PySWIP](http://code.google.com/p/pyswip/) that provides a bridge between Python and SWI-Prolog. The [wiki](http://code.google.com/p/pyswip/w/list) hosted on Google Code's project pages holds [installation instructions](http://code.google.com/p/pyswip/wiki/INSTALL) and some [usage examples](http://code.google.com/p/pyswip/wiki/Examples).

**EDIT (5th of July 2019)**

PySWIP now seems to be maintained on [Github](https://github.com/yuce/pyswip), with its own [installation instructions](https://github.com/yuce/pyswip/blob/master/INSTALL.md). TLDR: installing SWI-Prolog and `pip install pyswip` should do the job, for both Python 2 and 3.

Answer (score 4):

Since you don't want to "rewrite my current Prolog program," I think the natural approach is to make an external call from Python to SWI-Prolog, passing appropriate command line arguments.

Take a look at this SO discussion, [How to call external command in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/89228/487781), from Sept. 2008.  Using the `subprocess` module allows the stdout from an external command to be piped to the Python process and read as a stream there.

This reduces the problem to choosing [command line arguments](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%272.4%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/cmdline.html%27%29%29) for SWI-Prolog.  It is possible to invoke SWI-Prolog indirectly, through a shell-script on Unix-like systems or a "DOS" batch/cmd file on Windows, but I'll omit further mention of such an indirect call.

See especially the discussion in Sec. 2.4.2 of the SWI-Prolog manual (linked above) of `-g` and `-t` options.  For example:

```
swipl --quiet -t rD( [1,2,3,4,5,4], X ),halt
```

will likely do what you want.  The `--quiet` option suppresses the banner/welcome message, which you probably want to simplify parsing the output as received by Python.

Comment: Yeah, it is sort of variant. But not really usable

Comment: @garm0nboz1a:  If there are specific steps that need clarification, I'd be happy to try.  The approach would treat an SWI-Prolog program as a "black box".  Thus while the existing .pl coding "knows" nothing about the Python caller, such a caller must assume the burden of parsing the Prolog top-level query result and doing something appropriate with it, e.g. assigning to a variable.  Your example is not clear about whether Python code is required to "recognize" the data type of `result` or just treat all values as strings.  So there are many unexplored (by me) aspects to your question.

Answer (score 2):

An update for Python3, PySwip in PyPI at the time of writing is for legacy Python only, but the [source code on github](https://github.com/yuce/pyswip) is Python3 compatible. You can git clone this, run `python3 setup.py install` and it'll give you a Python3 version.

To consult an existing knowledge base, stored as knowledge_base.pl:

```
from pyswip import Prolog
prolog = Prolog()
prolog.consult("knowledge_base.pl")
for res in prolog.query("rD( [1,2,3,4,5,4], X )."):
    print(res)

# output:
# {'X': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
```

Comment: It seems to be installable again for Python 3 from pypi

Answer (score 0):

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

p = Popen('/usr/local/sicstus4.2.3/bin/sicstus', shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
cmd = open('/path/to/your/test.pl').read()
res = p.communicate(cmd)
for line in res:
    print line
```